# Conditional search for a DOCS spreasheet

Tags: search, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm working with two Sheets in docs, I want to bring the name of a product(Column 1) from one sheet to another(also in Column 1) but only if it has certain value in another column(Column 2), which is "Published"
Tried to use several formulas, but an if will keep spaces between published and non published products, so a script is what I need, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Are the two sheets within the same file?  If so, this formula may work:

`=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B="Published")`

If the columns are in different files then you would need to combine both Sheet1 ranges with an IMPORTRANGE formula:

`=FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet1!A:A"),IMPORTRANGE("key","Sheet1!B:B")="Published")`